# No sound in stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I used ffmpeg for live stream like below,

`ffmpeg -re -thread_queue_size 5512 -i "file.mp4" -i "file.mp3" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx`.

Here I don't have audio in video. Then I tried,

`ffmpeg -re -thread_queue_size 5512 -i "file.mp4" -map 0 -map -0:a -i "file.mp3" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx`
to remove audio from video, then I get error like,

> Option map (set input stream mapping) cannot be applied to input url file.mp3

How to fix it?

Comment: Try: `ffmpeg -re -thread_queue_size 5512 -an -i "file.mp4" -i "file.mp3" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx`